# Estimate multivariate distribution of dependent variables

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis

Let $H \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_H, {\sigma_H}^2)$ and $S \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_S, {\sigma_S}^2)$.
$H$ and $S$ are dependent of each other and their covariances are unknown, and they are *jointly* normal.

Let $G = H - S$ and the mean and variance of $G \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_G,{\sigma_G}^2)$ are known.

Is there a way to I estimate the multivariate normal distribution of the vector $(H,S)$?

Sorry to bother, if this question is trivial, but I'd appreciate help.

Comment: Since $H$ and $S$ are dependent, the assertion that their joint distribution is also normal is an _additional_ assumption. Do you make this additional assumption?

Comment: Yes, the joint distribution should be normal as well.